# Create extra Flag colours in Outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003

We are in a corporate environment across two sites located 200kms apart. We have shared Mailboxes in Outlook where we handle emails amongst the two sites.
We must use email for this process.

How do we create extra colored flags or emblems or avatars or whatever to flag emails that particular individual staff at both sites look at?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add colors in Outlook 2003. Outlook 2007 does have that ability, but it's tied to
the new colored categories.